# sum of integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $\mathbb{R}$.

$$f(x)=(-1)^nn,\  x\in A_n,\text{ and }A_n=\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right].$$
Compute $\displaystyle\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}f \, dx  $

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{A_n}f=-1(1/2)+2(1/6)-3(1/2)+\cdots,\tag{1}$$
This series converges, so I would say the the function is integrable. 
Is there a way to evaluate (1) without resorting to geometry? Can one be more thorough? Is there a closed form integral for $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{A_n}f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nn\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}=g(1),
$$
where 
$$
g:(-1,1] \to \mathbb{R},\
g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}x^{n+1}=-x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}x^{n+1}.
$$ 
For every $x \in (-1,1]$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
g(x)&=&-x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^x(-1)^nt^n\, dt=-x+\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t}\, dt=-x+\ln(1+x).
\end{eqnarray}
Hence 
$$
\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}f=g(1)=\ln2-1.
$$